# What does *dead* mean in *What do you mean, dead?*?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

[In the following sentence](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/121804), which I encountered when I was learning French on Duolingo (but my native language is not English):

> What do you mean, dead?

In my dictionary, there is no description of such use of *dead*. The closest one is likely the one equivalent to *absolutely*.

So what does *dead* mean in these cases? Does it mean the speaker does not understand what the listener was saying at all?

And also is it considered vulgar to use *dead* in these cases?

Comment: In what way does the dictionary definition of dead (opposite of alive) not fit here, in your opinion?

Comment: Sometimes it pays to say the meaning of the sentence out loud in your native tongue....Oh those poor suffering kids learning French on that site....:)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the construction *What do you mean, X?*, X is "echoic": a word or phrase (or even a complete sentence) quoted from the previous speaker's utterance. The construction may ask for confirmation or explanation of X, or it may express disbelief or shock.

> **A:** Our proposal is dead.
>   **B:** What do you mean, dead? As in the boss rejected it, or we're withdrawing it?
>
> **A:** Bill's dead.
>   **B:** What do you mean, dead? I spoke with him just yesterday!

ADDED: 
So X—*dead*, in your example—means just what it ordinarily means in the context in which the first speaker uttered it.

And of course (as Michael Harvey and David Richerby gently point out) X can be virtually anything:

> **A:** I've just finished the *Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics*.
>   **B:** What do you mean, the *Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics*? The assignment was the *Critique of Pure Reason*!

Comment: Your car's been stolen. What do you mean, stolen?

Comment: Or, to paraphrase your last example, A: I Kant. B: What do you mean, you Kant?

Comment: @JasonBassford I tried, but I Kuhn't come up with a better paradigm.

Comment: @StoneyB You couldn't Russell something up? Don't these pun threads Plato your advantage?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - this entire discussion is too Hume-anistic.

Comment: @BobJarvis Yeah. Maybe we need to Locke it down.

Comment: @StoneyB - this thread has definitely been run through the Mill.

Comment: Ah shucks, I missed this really good one. Question: What do mean, really good one? Answ: I mean you might get a case of echolalia, not to mention echopraxia, which, damn it, can be categorized properly as echophenomena. But it's all Greek to me. [Can I go home now, please? :)]

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised that no other answer yet has mentioned that what we have here is [a *mention*, not a *use*,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) of the word "dead." Properly punctuated, the sentence would be:

> What do you mean, "dead"?

or to use a slightly older punctuation style,

> What do you mean — "dead"?

That is, the speaker doesn't know what the addressee meant by the word "dead," and is asking for clarification.

> What do you mean by "dead"?

Omitting the quotation marks is just a colloquial shorthand (like using a short pause — indicated by comma or em-dash — instead of the word "by").

---

The other answerers are absolutely correct that most likely the speaker is trying to convey that he doesn't believe his ears.

> He's dead, Jim.
>
> What do you mean, "dead"? You mean, like, unconscious? In a coma? You can't possibly mean that he's *actually* dead!

---

Regarding the [use-mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction), consider the difference between

> VADER: Luke, I am your father.
>   LUKE [incredulous]: What do you mean, "father"?

and

> VADER: Luke, I am your father.
>   LUKE [immediately deferential]: What do you mean, father?

Comment: Vader says "NO I am your father"

Comment: I think it's more commonly interpreted as an indirect quotation and not a mention of the word, hence no quotation marks. Compare `A: I can't do it. - B: What do you mean, you can't?` and the (at least to me) more unusual `A: I can't do it. - B: What do you mean, "I can't"?`.

Comment: Thinking about it, there were a *lot* more dramatic possibilities in, "LUKE - I AM YOUR MOTHER!"  :-)

Comment: What do you mean, "What do you mean"?

Answer (score 6):

That would usually be said as an expression of disbelief on being told that someone is dead. It means the same as the everyday adjective *dead*, because that's what it is. You might consider it as ellipsis of "what do you mean, he's dead?"

Answer (score 3):

Here’s how this question might be used:

> Doctor: I’m sorry, but the patient is dead.
>
> Patient’s relative: What do you mean, dead?!
>
> Doctor: I’m very sorry for your loss.

In other words, someone would say this if they could not believe another person was dead even after being told of the fact.  It’s a rhetorical question; no answer is really expected. In my scenario the doctor could have said “Well, the patient stopped breathing and I don’t hear a pulse and they don’t respond to stimuli” but that would probably be tactless; the relative probably would not want to hear all about how the doctor knows the patient is dead upon learning of the death.

And no, it is not vulgar to say this, since you asked.

Comment: I wonder, does the OP think it might be vulgar to say 'dead' because so many people censor death and say that someone 'passed away' etc? I did once hear someone say that an aunt had 'crossed the Jordan'.

Comment: Wow... that’s quite the euphemism. Cultural differences, I guess. I could see that this might be the thinking, though of course would have to defer to the OP. Also, it should be noted that someone would likely be in an emotional state while saying this, so it’s not exactly a polite or restrained thing to say.

Comment: Also just noticed that the OP wonders if “dead” means “absolutely” in this context. No, *absolutely* not- it most certainly means “not alive.” An expression like “You are *dead wrong*” has this meaning of “absolutely.”

Comment: Mixolydian - I think you have to be sensitive to a bereaved person's feelings - when my own mother died I got so sick of people dressing it up with euphemisms. She was dead. She died. We all die.

Comment: The aunt who had crossed the Jordan had done so decades before. I forebore to ask if she was going to Israel, Jordan Syria, or the West Bank.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes I definitely agree with being sensitive to feelings. Sorry if there was confusion - when I said "someone would likely be in an emotional state while saying this/it's not polite" I was talking about the sentence in question, "What do you mean, dead?", in case that was misunderstood. If this was not actually a misunderstanding by you and I am the one with the misunderstanding, please disregard the above. Anyway, lol @ trying to figure out where and how she crossed the Jordan! Probably was for the best that you restrained yourself from asking. :)